# Question about positive recurrence of a Markov chain

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, markov-chains, martingales

Q) Let $\{X_n\}$ be an irreducible Markov chain on a countable set $S$. Suppose that for some $x_0$ and a non-negative function $f:S\to(0,\infty)$, there is a constant $0<\alpha<1$ s.t.

$$\mathbb{E}_xf(X_1)\leq \alpha f(x)\text{ for all }x\neq x_0$$

Suppose also that $f(x_0)\leq f(x)$ for all $x$. Show that $\{X_n\}$ is positive recurrent.

Let $Y_n = f(X_n)/\alpha^n$ and I can show that $Y_n$ is a supermartingale using the hypothesis. But to show $X_n$ is positive recurrent, since $x_0$ is mentioned, I was thinking of the stopping time

$$\tau = \inf\{n\geq 0:X_n = x_0\}$$

Then $Y_{n\wedge \tau}$ is also a supermartingale, $\mathbb{E}_xY_{n\wedge \tau}\leq f(x)$.

1) How can I show that $\mathbb{E}_x\tau < \infty$ which shows that $x_0$ is positive recurrent?

2) How does that show the chain is positive recurrent?

Comment: $\mathbb E_xf(X_1)$ presumably denoting $\mathbb E[f(X_1)\mid X_0=x]$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of the following theorem.

**Theorem**. If $X_n$ is a nonnegative supermartingale and $N \le \infty$ is a stopping time, then $EX_0 \ge EX_N$ where $X_\infty = \lim X_n$ (which exists by the martingale convergence theorem).

I will continue from where you left off. You've already proven that $E_xY_n$ is a nonnegative supermartingale, and $\tau$ is a stopping time. Hence
$$ f(x) = E_xY_0 \ge E_xY_\tau = E_x(Y_\tau;\tau=\infty) + E_x(Y_\tau;\tau<\infty)$$
$$\ge E_x(Y_\infty; \tau = \infty) = E_x(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(X_n)/\alpha^n; \tau=\infty) $$
$$ \ge E_x(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_0)/\alpha^n; \tau=\infty) . $$
Since $f(x_0) > 0, 0 < \alpha < 1$ and the term $f(x_0)/\alpha^n \rightarrow \infty$, it follows that $P_x(\tau = \infty) = 0$, and $P_x(\tau < \infty) = 1$ for all $x \in S$. Hence $P_x(X_n=x_0\; i.o.) =1$, and  $x_0$ is recurrent.

Recall the chain is irreducible and $x_0$ is recurrent, hence all states $x \in S$ are recurrent (irreducibility $ \Rightarrow \rho_{x_0x} > 0$, additionally $x_0$ is recurrent $\Rightarrow \rho_{xx} = 1$ where $\rho_{xy}\equiv P_x(T_y < \infty)$).

Comment: I see, may I know why $E_xY_{\tau}\geq E_x(Y_{\infty};\tau=\infty)$? Is it because $Y_{\tau} = Y_{\infty}$ and if we take expectation over a smaller set $\tau = \infty$, then it yields $E_xY_{\tau}\geq E_x(Y_{\infty};\tau=\infty)$.

Comment: Also, in $E_x(Y_{\infty};\tau=\infty) = E_x(\lim_{n\to \infty} f(X_n)/\alpha^n;\tau=\infty)$, may I know why we can move the limit out? Is that because existence of $Y_{\infty}$ implies $Y_n$ is bounded and hence the limit comes out by bounded convergence theorem?

Comment: I added an extra step to clarify regarding your first question (you are right). There is no need to move the $\lim_n$ out of $E_x$. I have edited the answer to address these two issues. Thanks for pointing out.